# Question regarding bounds for Uniform Joint Distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I am doing joint probability and i came across a problem with bounds of the joint probability.

> Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent and uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$. Compute $Pr(X ≥
> Y Z)$.

From the solutions:

\begin{align*}
Pr\{X \geq YZ\} &= \int \int \int_{x \geq yz} f_{XYZ}(x, y, z) \, dx \, dy \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{yz}^1 1 \, dx \, dy \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (1 - yz) \, dy \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \left(1 - \frac{z}{2}\right) \, dz \\
&= \frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}

What i am unsure of is the step:
\begin{align*}
&= \int \int \int_{x \geq yz} f_{XYZ}(x, y, z) \, dx \, dy \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{yz}^1 1 \, dx \, dy \, dz \\
\end{align*}

Why is intuitive reasoning on why the first 2 integral bounds are from 0 to 1. I am thinking of it as they are uniformly distributed hence defined over 0 to 1 as stated, but I dont feel convinced by it.

Thank you

Comment: $x,y,z$ are between $1$ and $1$ and there is only one restriction: $x \geq yz$. Once this is taken care of, there is no further restriction on $y$ and $z$.